# Series to Dataframe conversion with column indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

There is a Series called `location_ratings` as below :

```
location_ratings = location['Location'].value_counts()
```

Below is the location_ratings's sample output:

```
 Location
 Brazil                                       180
 Alaska                                       175
 Russia                                       171
 Colombia                                     146
 Canada                                       144
 California                                   142
 France                                       130
 England                                      104
 India                                         97
 Indonesia                                     84
 China                                         83
```

There are 2 values one is the location and the other one is a numeric value (ratings).

I want to separate them into two new columns, one should be the 'Location' the other should be 'Ratings' in a dataframe.

I tried converting the Series to dataframe and then resetting the index using below code but failed to get the expected result.

Failed attempt 1 :

```
D1 = location_ratings.to_frame().reset_index().T
```

Failed attempt 2 :

```
D1 = location_ratings.to_frame().
D1.columns = ['Location', 'Ratings']
```

Comment: doesn't `D1 = location_ratings.to_frame().reset_index()` work?

Comment: Why are you taking the transpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can first change index name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`) and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
location = pd.DataFrame({'Location': {0: 'Brazil', 1: 'Brazil', 2: 'Brazil', 3: 'Brazil', 4: 'Brazil', 5: 'Alaska', 6: 'Alaska', 7: 'Alaska', 8: 'Alaska'}})
print (location)
  Location
0   Brazil
1   Brazil
2   Brazil
3   Brazil
4   Brazil
5   Alaska
6   Alaska
7   Alaska
8   Alaska

location_ratings = location['Location'].value_counts().rename_axis('Location')
print (location_ratings)
Location
Brazil    5
Alaska    4
Name: Location, dtype: int64

D1 = location_ratings.reset_index(name='Ratings')
print (D1)
  Location  Ratings
0   Brazil        5
1   Alaska        4
```

Another solution with assigning new column names:

```
D1 = location_ratings.reset_index()
D1.columns = ['Location', 'Ratings']
print (D1)
  Location  Ratings
0   Brazil        5
1   Alaska        4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
D1 = location_ratings.rename_axis('Location').reset_index(name='Ratings')
```